# ObjectInputStream - reading large binary file - problems with memory

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

Before I proceed to my question : please note that I am not working on any client-server application that would require serialization, but the program I am trying to customize stores one big instance of one big class in a .dat file. I have read about this issue (memory leak in ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream)and the fact that I could probably need to :

- use the ObjectOutputStream.reset() method after writing the class instance in the .dat file, so that it doesn't hold the reference anymore;
- re-write the code without using serialization;
- split the file and read it in chunks;
- change the JVM memory parameter by using -Xmx;

So, I was provided with one class that generates a language model and saves it with a .dat extension; the code was probably optimized for small model files (there are 2 model files provided as examples, both around 10MB ), but I generated a much larger model class, and it is around 40MB. Then, there is another class in another folder, totally independent on the first one, that uses this model, and the model has to be loaded using ObjectInputStream. Here comes the problem : a classic "OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space".

Writing the object:

```
try {
  // Create an output stream to the file.
  FileOutputStream file_output = new FileOutputStream (file);
  ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream( file_output ); 
  o.writeObject(this); 
  file_output.close ();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println ("IO exception = " + e );
}
```

Reading the object:

```
InputStream model = null;
ModelGeneration oRead = null;
ObjectInputStream p = null; 

try {
  model = new FileInputStream(filename);
  BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(model);
  p = new ObjectInputStream(buf);
  oRead = (ModelGeneration) p.readObject();
  p.reset();

} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  try {
    model.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I tried to use the reset() method, but it is useless because we load only one instance of one class at a time, nothing else needed. This is why I can't split the file, too: only one class instance is stored in the .dat file.

Changing the heap space seems like a worse solution than optimizing the code.

I would really appreciate your advice on what I can do.

Btw the code is here : http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/addons/trunk/Tagger/, I only implemented the required classes for a different language.

P.S. Works fine if I create a smaller model, but I would prefer the bigger one.

Comment: Code that forms part of a question must be included in the question, not posted elsewhere.

Comment: I didn't post it elsewhere. It's open source , thus the link.

Comment: It doesn't matter who posted it elsewhere. It *is* posted elsewhere, not as part of this question. And the code you've posted doesn't compile. ObjectInputStream.reset() doesn't exist.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset() - it does. And the code compiles.

Comment: According to the info I found, reset() has to be called both when writing the object to file and reading it from the file. But it doesn't help anyway.

Comment: It's inherited from InputStream, not part of ObjectInputStream. It doesn't do what ObjectOutputStream.reset() does: it works in conjunction with mark(), which has nothing to do with your problem. This code will throw an IOException when you call reset(). What you read was incorrect. And you should be closing 'o', not 'file_output'.

Comment: OK, I agree, but at my current level all I can do is search for possible solutions on the net. I used the reset() on both Input and Output, then separately, but no exceptions were thrown, but the problem with memory remains. Do you have any suggestions? Btw what does "Lopes" mean?

Comment: I don't see that you can do anything except reduce the size of your object. The reset() method only helps if you're writing multiple objects.

Comment: Yes, I know it… The smaller model works anyway. But maybe compress the files even more?

Comment: How would that help? You still have to reconstruct the object in memory. Size on the disk is irrelevant.